# Невозможно использовать приватные поля в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создал CustomFormatAttribute и повесил на приватные поля в юнити. Мне нужно узнать значение этих полей для дальнейшего использования. Этот код работает на полях с публичным доступом, но для приватных полей если в getfield добавить этот параметр BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, то юнити зависает.
Как решить эту проблему? возможно ли иначе узнать значение приватных полей на которых установлен CustomFormatAttribute?

```
        List<Component> components = new List<Component>();
        GameObject[] gameObjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

        foreach (GameObject obj in gameObjects)
        {
            Component[] component = obj.GetComponents<Component>();
            components.AddRange(component);
        }

        foreach (var item in components)
        {
            FieldInfo[] fields = item.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                 var value = field.GetValue(item);
                 var attribute = field.GetCustomAttribute<CustomFormatAttribute>();
                 Debug.Log(value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Во имя каких чертей ты это делаешь? Покайся безумец! Ограждать ПРИВАТНОЕ поле от неверного формата... боишься что сам укажешь неверный формат при написании класса и поэтому нужно нагородить пандусов везде, где только можно включая потолок? Будь поле хоть публичное, если параметры не валидны нужно, как нормальные человеки кидать `Exception` и все! А ваще в `Unity` атрибуты делаются через наследование от [PropertyAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html), но и они исключительно для сериализуемых полей!!! Использовать приватные поля в юнити ОЧЕНЬ ДАЖЕ ВОЗМОЖНО!

Comment: Мне это нужно для того чтобы выводить некоторые поля на экран для дебага. Я попробую использовать PropertyAttribute.

Comment: В конец не адекватная причина использования рекусии или атрибута. Можно было обойтись и `Debug.Log()`. А для отображения в реальном времени как дебаг, в юнити используют `OnGUI()` и рисуют цифры прямо на экрана, как [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Pool.ObjectPool_1.html), хоть график строй. Проблема решается одним методом с одной строчкой код.